# 日本語に違和感: さらに別の回答を追加する時にでるアラートダイアログの文言

Tags: バグ, 完了, 翻訳, 日本語

[image: ダイアログ]

> 別の回答を追加してよろしいですか?
>
> または、編集リンクを使用して、既存の回答を微調整および改善することもできます。

- 「追加してよろしいですか?」: システム側が回答を追加するかのように聞こえる
- 「回答を微調整」: 聞き慣れない組み合わせ

原文

> Are you sure you want to add another answer?
>
> You could use the edit link to refine and improve your existing answer, instead.

Answer (score 1):

> 本当に新しく回答を投稿しますか？
>
> 投稿済みの回答を修正・改善したい場合は編集機能が使えます。

雰囲気をテスト:

```
confirm("本当に新しく回答を投稿しますか？\n\n投稿済みの回答を修正・改善したい場合は編集機能が使えます。");
```

Comment: 翻訳を更新しました。次回のビルドに適用します。

Answer (score 0):

元の英語：

> Are you sure you want to add another answer? You could use the edit link to refine and improve your existing answer, instead.

雰囲気の翻訳（適当）：

> 同じ質問を2回を回答したいですか？編集機能を使って、最初の回答を改善したらどうですか？

Answer (score 0):

元の英語：

> Are you sure you want to add another answer?

entoさんとjmacさんの訳を混ぜてみました。

和訳案：

> 同じ質問に２つめの回答を投稿しますか？

Answer (score 0):

何言ってるかわからなかったので、chromeの警告だと思ってスルーしてました。
私ならこう書きます。

> 本当に新しい回答として追加しますか。質問を追加する前に、既存のあなたの回答を編集し改善することもできます。